# How to auto reload external code changes in Eclipse project ?

Tags: eclipse, ide, sublimetext3

I have started using Sublime text as my preferred code editor. But, I still rely on Eclipse for my maven build, server, and more.

Working on multiple editors could lead to another problem: whenever I make a change in some file outside of Eclipse, the IDE does not reload in the background. The files doesn't seem to sync, and I have to switch into Eclipse and make sure the changes are detected, then I can reload my page.

Doing 500 times of these in a day is annoying, does anybody have the same workflow and figure it out the solution for this, please let me know.

I am running on

Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Sublime Text 3

Feel free to suggest me anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Workspace` and check `Refresh on access`. If that doesn't solve your problem check `Refresh using hooks or polling` also.

Comment: Since I am using Mac the correct step should be : `Eclipse` -> `Preferences` -> Expand `General` -> Click on `Workspace` ... then applied the settings.

Comment: I notice the changes are pulling into Eclipse, but that kind of take about 3-5 seconds. But yes, your suggestion is solve my problem. I will make sure to accept it when I can.